# Trying to get property 'courses' of non-object

Tags: php, database, laravel, migration

I made php artisan migrate:fresh in my Laravel application but when i creating a new user I got this error

```
Trying to get property 'courses' of non-object (View: /Applications/AMPPS/www/zenit/resources/views/home.blade.php)
```

I have a table called courses which is empty. How can I solve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

Comment: can you show us some code ?

Answer (score 0):

**php artisan migrate:fresh** is used for dropping and creating all the tables again. You are trying to access an object that is not fetched. Please check you method where *home view* is used. At that place check the response and also use **dd($database_response)** for getting reponse in browser. hope that it will help you

Comment: Ok I think the problem might be that I try to get courses in the controller which don't exists. I send                                      
$courses = Course::orderBy('title')->get(); to the view. How can I define the variable $courses if there are no courses as in my case?